# unable to split a class with static member functions in header and source file

Tags: c++, split, singleton, implementation, static-members

I am using a simple log class to debug my code. The code has been downloaded from http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/logging-in-c/201804215?pgno=1 and is a log class implemented entirely in a header file.

For reason of clarity and building difficulties caused by the absence of an object file, I would like to split the implementation from declarations. That is move the code implementation to a cpp file.

Once I move the implementation details to a .cpp file , I end up getting alot of "undefined reference" linker errors to all the static member functions. The errors originate from the rest of my code. Anywhere I call the logging function from.

Is the problem related to the internal linkage that static member functions in .cpp file have? If so what options do I have to achieve splitting the file?
One option would be to remove the class encapsulation and reimplement it as non-OO code. I would rather avoid that too, is there something else?

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    FILELog::ReportingLevel() = FILELog::FromString(argv[1] ? argv[1] : "DEBUG1");
        const int count = 3;
    FILE_LOG(logDEBUG) << "A loop with " << count << " iterations";
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
            FILE_LOG(logDEBUG1) << "the counter i = " << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**log.hpp**

```
#ifndef __LOG_H__
#define __LOG_H__

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


#ifndef FILELOG_MAX_LEVEL
#define FILELOG_MAX_LEVEL logDEBUG4
#endif

#define FILE_LOG(level) \
    if (level > FILELOG_MAX_LEVEL) ;\
    else if (level > FILELog::ReportingLevel() || !Output2FILE::Stream()) ; \
    else FILELog().Get(level)


enum TLogLevel 
{
    logERROR, 
    logWARNING, 
    logINFO, 
    logDEBUG, 
    logDEBUG1, 
    logDEBUG2, 
    logDEBUG3, 
    logDEBUG4
};

class Output2FILE
{
public:
    static FILE*& Stream();
    static void Output(const std::string& msg);
};


template <typename T>
class Log
{
public:
    Log();
    virtual ~Log();
    std::ostringstream& Get(TLogLevel level = logINFO);
public:
    static TLogLevel& ReportingLevel();
    static std::string ToString(TLogLevel level);
    static TLogLevel FromString(const std::string& level);
protected:
    std::ostringstream os;
private:
    Log(const Log&);
    Log& operator =(const Log&);
};

//class FILELog : public Log<Output2FILE> {};
typedef Log<Output2FILE> FILELog;


#endif //__LOG_H__
```

log.cpp

```
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "log.hpp"

inline std::string NowTime()
{
    char buffer[11];
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    //tm r = {0};
    tm r = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%X", localtime_r(&t, &r));
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    char result[100] = {0};
    sprintf(result, "%s.%03ld", buffer, (long)tv.tv_usec / 1000); 
    return result;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
Log<T>::Log()
{
}

template <typename T>
std::ostringstream& Log<T>::Get(TLogLevel level)
{
    os << "- " << NowTime();
    os << " " << ToString(level) << ": ";
    os << std::string(level > logDEBUG ? level - logDEBUG : 0, '\t');
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
Log<T>::~Log()
{
    os << std::endl;
    T::Output(os.str());
}

template <typename T>
TLogLevel& Log<T>::ReportingLevel()
{
    static TLogLevel reportingLevel = logDEBUG4;
    return reportingLevel;
}

template <typename T>
std::string Log<T>::ToString(TLogLevel level)
{
    static const char* const buffer[] = {"ERROR", "WARNING", "INFO", "DEBUG", "DEBUG1", "DEBUG2", "DEBUG3", "DEBUG4"};
    return buffer[level];
}

template <typename T>
TLogLevel Log<T>::FromString(const std::string& level)
{
    if (level == "DEBUG4")
        return logDEBUG4;
    if (level == "DEBUG3")
        return logDEBUG3;
    if (level == "DEBUG2")
        return logDEBUG2;
    if (level == "DEBUG1")
        return logDEBUG1;
    if (level == "DEBUG")
        return logDEBUG;
    if (level == "INFO")
        return logINFO;
    if (level == "WARNING")
        return logWARNING;
    if (level == "ERROR")
        return logERROR;
    Log<T>().Get(logWARNING) << "Unknown logging level '" << level << "'. Using INFO level as default.";
    return logINFO;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

inline FILE*& Output2FILE::Stream()
{
    static FILE* pStream = stderr;
    return pStream;
}

inline void Output2FILE::Output(const std::string& msg)
{   
    FILE* pStream = Stream();
    if (!pStream)
        return;
    fprintf(pStream, "%s", msg.c_str());
    fflush(pStream);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a .cpp file with the implementation details of your logger? You should probably post the stuff that *doesn't work* that you need help fixing, not the stuff that does work!

Comment: You can't put template implementation in source files - they **have** to be in the header files.

Comment: @immibis true true. fixed that

Comment: @Amit I have read that somewhere while trying to figure out how to do that. But here it says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Standard rule for all online code help: post only a minimum program that indicates the problem, including all components, and the errors that you get.

Comment: @KarenRei Indeed I try to do that, but I honestly fail to separate this code in smaller chunks. It just looks like a solid block that I do not know how to split - and this is what I was trying to do in the 1st place. So please bear with me here. Thank you

Comment: @nass - I don't see how that question contradicts my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly instantiate type you are using - `Log<Output2FILE>`, so put following line:

```
 template class Log<Output2FILE>;
```

somewhere in `log.cpp` file after templates are defined. You will have to explicitly instantiate all types you will use with this template, or make template code available to other compilation units.

Comment: Dude you are nothing sort of a c++ God to me! I had been lost with this the whole day! Could you elaborate what you mean with "or make template code available to other compilation units". How do I do that? (or provide a link for a tutorial.

Comment: @nass make it available means to put it into header. Btw most code on your template does not depend on <T> so you may want to make base non templated class, move such functionality there implement in .cpp regular way. Then inherit template from that base and only implement what really uses `T`. In that case you may leave that templated code in header as it would be pretty small.